# Conda create frome file take so long

Tags: python, virtualenv, conda

I use `conda` commands to export env to a file on my pc and create new env on other pc using creating file.

`conda env create --prefix ./envs -f myenv.yml`

but after this command take so time and long and infinite time displaying `Installing pip dependencies: \`
Why? and How solve it this problem?

Comment: Are you using windows?

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, thanks for attention. No I use Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a discussion about this issue here: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/7690 with some possible random fixes. I've been digging about this, and it seems there is no clear solution up to now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conda sometimes gets hung up for no reason. If stuck for "infinite time", try hitting the ENTER key or Ctrl+c one time. This helps the console catch up to the actual processes are doing.
If it is actually a problem with pip, try to verify your connection to pip by running pip commands. You could also try removing those dependencies from the yml and see if the env creation still gets hung up (you can always add them manually afterwards).

Comment: I am going through the same problem when trying to use ``conda create -n xxxx -c conda-forge python=3 .... '' . I also tried to install mamba, and run `` mamba create -n xxxx -c conda-forge python=3 ... '' but it does not solve the problem.